# AngularJs ng-repeat not rendering data yet http 200 response

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is for an academic assignment. It is my first time using Angularjs and I am trying to display data onto the webpage. On the Chrome console I am getting a http response code 200 which means I am successfully getting the data but it just does not seem to be displaying.

groups.html :

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src = "groups.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="groupsCtrl">
    <div class="group-jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Champion's League Groups</h1>
        <p class="lead">The 2018–19 UEFA Champions League group stage began on 18 September and is scheduled to end on 12 December 2018. <br/>
            A total of 32 teams compete in the group stage to decide the 16 places in the knockout phase of the 2018–19 UEFA Champions League.</p>
        <hr class="my-1">
        <p>Information about each group can be seen below</p>
    </div>
     <div class="addGroup-Title">
        <h4 class="display-6">Groups:</h4>

          <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Group Letter</th>
            <th>Number of Teams</th>
            <th>Matches Played</th>
            <th>Top Goalscorer</th>
            <th>Top Assists</th>
            <th>Most Cards</th>
            <th>Total Points</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="group in leagueGroup">
            <td>{{group.groupLetter}}</td>
            <td>{{group.numberOfTeams}}</td>
            <td>{{group.totalMatchesPlayed}}</td>
            <td>{{group.topGoalscorer}}</td>
            <td>{{group.topAssists}}</td>
            <td>{{group.mostCards}}</td>
            <td>{{group.totalPoints}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
     </div>
    <div class="addGroup-Title">
        <h4 class="display-6">Add a New Group:</h4>


    <form ng-show="showForm" ng-submit="submitNewGroupForm()" style="margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 10px" ng-model="newGroup">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="AddGroupLetter">Group Letter:</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="newGroup.groupLetter"class="form-control" id="AddGroupLetter" min="1" max="2" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="AddnumTeams">Number of Teams:</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="AddnumTeams" ng-model="newGroup.numberOfTeams" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="AddTotalMatches">Total Matches Played:</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="AddTotalMatches" ng-model="newGroup.totalMatchesPlayed" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="AddTotalPoints">Total Points:</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="AddTotalPoints" ng-model="newGroup.totalPoints" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="AddTopGoalscorer">Top Goalscorer:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AddTopGoalscorer" ng-model="newGroup.topGoalscorer" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="AddTopAssists">Top Assists:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AddTopAssists" ng-model="newGroup.topAssists" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="AddMostCards">Most Cards</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AddMostCards" ng-model="newGroup.mostCards" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Create A Group</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="addGroup-Title">
        <h4 class="display-6">Delete a Group:</h4>

        <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="DeleteGroup">ID of Group</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DeleteGroup" ng-model="groupData.groupId" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Delete A Group</button>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

groups.js :

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.groups', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/groups', {
        templateUrl: 'groups/groups.html',
        controller: 'groupsCtrl'
    });
}])

.controller('groupsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.leagueGroup = [];
    $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/groups')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.leagueGroup = response.data;
        });

    $scope.submitNewGroupForm = function () {
        $scope.newGroup =
            {
                groupId: getgroupId(),
                groupLetter: $scope.newGroup.groupLetter,
                numberOfTeams: $scope.newGroup.numberOfTeams,
                totalMatchesPlayed: $scope.newGroup.totalMatchesPlayed,
                topGoalscorer: $scope.newGroup.topGoalscorer,
                topAssists: $scope.newGroup.topAssists,
                mostCards: $scope.newGroup.mostCards,
                totalPoints: $scope.newGroup.totalPoints
            };

        $http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/groups', $scope.newGroup)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.response = response.data;
                  alert('Created new Group: ' + $scope.response.stadiumName);
            });
    };

    $http.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/groups/'+ $scope.groupData.groupId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.response = response.data;
                });
    });
        function getgroupId() {
            return Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) + 10);
        }
```

Data example:

```
groupId: 1
groupLetter: "A"
mostCards: "Marcos Rojo"
numberOfTeams: 4
topAssists: "Kevin De Bruyne"
topGoalscorer: "Cristiano Ronaldo"
totalMatchesPlayed: 6
totalPoints: 48
```

response(chrome dev):

```
[  
   {  
      "groupId":1,
      "groupLetter":"A",
      "mostCards":"Marcos Rojo",
      "numberOfTeams":4,
      "topAssists":"Kevin De Bruyne",
      "topGoalscorer":"Cristiano Ronaldo",
      "totalMatchesPlayed":6,
      "totalPoints":48
   },
   {  
      "groupId":2,
      "groupLetter":"B",
      "mostCards":"Ander Herrera",
      "numberOfTeams":4,
      "topAssists":"Luka Modric",
      "topGoalscorer":"Sergio Aguero",
      "totalMatchesPlayed":6,
      "totalPoints":36
   },
   {  
      "groupId":3,
      "groupLetter":"C",
      "mostCards":"Sergio Ramos",
      "numberOfTeams":4,
      "topAssists":"Xavi",
      "topGoalscorer":"Lionel Messi",
      "totalMatchesPlayed":6,
      "totalPoints":50
   },
   {  
      "groupId":4,
      "groupLetter":"D",
      "mostCards":"Virgil Van Dijk",
      "numberOfTeams":4,
      "topAssists":"Neymar",
      "topGoalscorer":"Kylian MBappe",
      "totalMatchesPlayed":6,
      "totalPoints":32
   }
]
```

Comment: A few questions: can you include an example of what `response.data` is? Have you set a breakpoint in that response handler function to inspect the data? Have you been able to render other data from that controller in the view?

Comment: console.log your leagueGroup to see what is being returned and if it matches the expected structure for the ng-repeat. Alo - it could just be the ocde you have posted - but you are not closing the .controller declaration in Group,js

Comment: yeah its just the code i posted. ill post a screenshot of what the data looks like. im not too confident on this so havent set any breakpoints or anything

Comment: Are you using ng-controller anywhere in your code?

Comment: @JamesBrunet yes ive updated my html above

Comment: Try adding $scope.leagueGroup = []; on the second line of your controller.

Comment: @austince example data added above?

Comment: @JamesBrunet before the $scope.leagueGroup = response.data or after?

Comment: Before the $http.get..

Comment: But are you formatting your data correctly?

Comment: Your data will need to be returned as a json object.

Comment: @JamesBrunet it didnt have any effect on it displaying. yes i am using jsonify

Comment: If you go to your Chrome console and click on Network and then on the HTTP call, what data do you see is returned?

Comment: @JamesBrunet yes i see it all.. ill add it above

Comment: I've just realised that you are referrencing ng-controller twice: once in your body and once in the div. Try removing one reference.

Comment: no i added the second to try and fix it. removed it but no luck still. all that is displaying is the table headers :(

Comment: You definitely don't want `ng-controller="groupsCtrl"` on the `<body>` tag outside of your `ng-app`, though probably not your problem. Could you post the rest of the controller code? And the full HTML file? Perhaps make a Snippet example in the question (click the <> icon in the toolbar)?

Comment: @austince ive updated above thanks ill maybe remove it from that tag

Comment: Hey yeah it still doesn't look like you're including the full JavaScript or HTML. Please include the entire file.

Comment: @austince thats everything i have added now

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of head banging it turns out in my groups.js i am calling all of my methods such as http.get in the same functions. They need to be called on seperate functions so that they all dont run when the screen loads. Once i re-organised into seperate functions the data displayed.

Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: Can you post what your final code looked like to help others if they fall into this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a `console.log` with the response object to ensure it's what you expect it to be?

Do it here:

```
.then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.leagueGroup = response.data;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
```

Have you tried doing a $scope.$apply() after you assign the data?

Another option to confirm that your data is correct is to simply put a `<pre>` tag in your template to confirm the data is bound, like this:
`<pre>{{leagueGroup}}</pre>`

Comment: im using pycharm, could u show me how to do the console.log based on my code? and also the apply?

Comment: You should open up the browser debug tools. Right-Click -> Inspect on chrome.

Comment: @AaronRogers the reason I'm asking about the console.log is a hunch that the data you are binding to may not be the correct shape.

Comment: @jonnycraze when i run that then where do i view the console?

Answer (score 0):

Your module name seems to be wrong. You've named it `myApp.groups` but it should just be `myApp`.

```
angular.module('myApp.groups', ['ngRoute'])
```

Should be:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
```

Are you getting any errors in the console?

```js
const data = [{
    "groupId": 1,
    "groupLetter": "A",
    "mostCards": "Marcos Rojo",
    "numberOfTeams": 4,
    "topAssists": "Kevin De Bruyne",
    "topGoalscorer": "Cristiano Ronaldo",
    "totalMatchesPlayed": 6,
    "totalPoints": 48
  },
  {
    "groupId": 2,
    "groupLetter": "B",
    "mostCards": "Ander Herrera",
    "numberOfTeams": 4,
    "topAssists": "Luka Modric",
    "topGoalscorer": "Sergio Aguero",
    "totalMatchesPlayed": 6,
    "totalPoints": 36
  },
  {
    "groupId": 3,
    "groupLetter": "C",
    "mostCards": "Sergio Ramos",
    "numberOfTeams": 4,
    "topAssists": "Xavi",
    "topGoalscorer": "Lionel Messi",
    "totalMatchesPlayed": 6,
    "totalPoints": 50
  },
  {
    "groupId": 4,
    "groupLetter": "D",
    "mostCards": "Virgil Van Dijk",
    "numberOfTeams": 4,
    "topAssists": "Neymar",
    "topGoalscorer": "Kylian MBappe",
    "totalMatchesPlayed": 6,
    "totalPoints": 32
  }
];

const app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app
.controller('groupsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

  $timeout(1000)
    .then(function() {
      $scope.leagueGroup = data;
    });

}])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="groupsCtrl">

      <div class="addGroup-Title">
        <h4 class="display-6">Groups:</h4>

        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Group Letter</th>
              <th>Number of Teams</th>
              <th>Matches Played</th>
              <th>Top Goalscorer</th>
              <th>Top Assists</th>
              <th>Most Cards</th>
              <th>Total Points</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="group in leagueGroup">
              <td>{{group.groupLetter}}</td>
              <td>{{group.numberOfTeams}}</td>
              <td>{{group.totalMatchesPlayed}}</td>
              <td>{{group.topGoalscorer}}</td>
              <td>{{group.topAssists}}</td>
              <td>{{group.mostCards}}</td>
              <td>{{group.totalPoints}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear! Please accept the answer whenever you're ready.

Comment: i mean your code works on the snippet.. my problem still remains :(